# Moving different Elements on the same JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

So, I have gotten a ways since my last question, and have changed the way I am doing everything now.

My current question is this: I have three buttons and a text field that I want to add to my singular JPanel. I want the text field to be below the buttons a ways and centered. Is there a way I can do this easily with a normal layout, and how do I do such a thing?

*Code here*

```
public class FarkleWindow extends JFrame{
public FarkleWindow()
{
    this.setTitle("Farkle!");
    this.setSize(windowWidth,windowHeight);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    inititalizeWindow();
    addButtonListener();

    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void inititalizeWindow() {

    gameBoard = new FarkleGameBoard();
    game = new FarkleGame();

    roll = new JButton("Roll First Time");
    reroll = new JButton("Roll Again!");
    endTurn = new JButton("Let The Other Player Roll!");

    gameBoard.add(roll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    gameBoard.add(reroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    gameBoard.add(endTurn, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    playerTurn = new JTextField();
    if(game.isPlayer1Turn())
        playerTurn.setText(game.getP1() + "\'s Score Turn Score Is " + game.getTurnScore());
    else
        playerTurn.setText(game.getP2() + "\'s Score Turn Score Is " + game.getTurnScore());

    playerTurn.setEditable(false);

    gameBoard.add(playerTurn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.add(gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);   
    repaint();
}
}

public class FarkleGameBoard extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{   
    g.setColor(mainBackGround);
    g.fillRect(0,0,2*playerDiceWidth+tossingAreaWidth+2*player1diceX, 
                playerDiceHeight+2*player1diceY);

    g.setColor(diceArea);
    g.fillRect(player1diceX,player1diceY,playerDiceWidth, playerDiceHeight);
    g.fillRect(player1diceX+tossingAreaWidth,player1diceY,playerDiceWidth, playerDiceHeight);

    g.setColor(scoreBoard);
    g.fillRect(player1diceX+playerDiceWidth+currentScoreX, player1diceY+currentScoreY,
        currentScoreWidth,currentScoreHeight);
    g.fillRect(player1diceX+playerDiceWidth+runScoreX, player1diceY+runScoreY,
        runScoreWidth,runScoreHeight);
}
}
```

After reading some of the API, I am generally just confused about the Layout Managers and how exactly they work. Any help would be great.

Comment: `The thing is that I want to use just one panel to do all of that still using the layout manager.` Why??? Don't force yourself to be limited. Many time the code to do this will be far harder to change/maintain and you never know when the requirements will change. For example if you want to add a 4th button, the code is not as straight forward as you think. Adding the button is easy, but then you also have to change the constraint for the text field. This is not really a good design. The text field should be displayed independently of the number of buttons on the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple different ways you might achieve this, which you use will depend on the desired results you are after, for example, you could simply use `GridBagLayout`

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
panel.add(new JButton("Roll First Time"), gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
panel.add(new JButton("Roll Again"), gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
panel.add(new JButton("Let the other player roll"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
// You could also use a EmptyBorder
gbc.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 0, 0);
gbc.gridwidth = 3;
panel.add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
```

Or you could use a compounding approach, using multiple layout managers to achieve  the result your after...

[image: Compound Layouts]

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
buttons.add(new JButton("Roll First Time"));
buttons.add(new JButton("Roll Again"));
buttons.add(new JButton("Let the other player roll"));

JPanel field = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
field.add(new JTextField(10));

JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
main.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
main.add(field);
```

This might be slightly better, as the field will always be within the centre of the available space of the parent container...

Comment: The thing is that I want to use just one panel to do all of that still using the layout manager. Is this still possible?

Comment: Isn't that what the first example does?

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that. Would using the GridBagLayout like that affect anything I have in my paintComponent?

Comment: Possibly, but that's not just limited to `GridBagLayout`, each platform can render fonts differently, meaning that the position of the components can change from system to system.  Much of your painting could be done by extending `JPanel`, painting the background the way you want it and then using appropriate layouts to position them and letting the layout manager do it's job

Answer (score 1):

Create one panel for the buttons:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(button1);
buttonPanel.add(button2);
buttonPanel.add(button3);
```

Create another panel for the text field:

```
JPanel textPanel = new JPanel( FlowLayout.CENTER );
textPanel.add( textField );
```

Now maybe use a BoxLayout to display the panels vertically and add this panel to the frame:

```
Box main = Box.createVerticalBox();
main.add(buttonPanel);
main.add(textPanel);
add(main, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Never think that you have to use one panel. Just break the layout down logically.

Of course there are many ways to do this. This is just one approach. Learn the basics of each layout manager from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)